# Unable to access StorageGrid from S3 Browser

Tags: cloud-object-storage

I am using S3 browser to connect to my StorageGrid resource. However I get the following error- : "Task failed (System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: Invalid port specified.)". The port number I am using is 9020. I am able to accessto the same storageGrid resource with 9020 in another browser.

tried a few alternate port numbers but with no success